# Review audits heads up: upvote doesn't count for real

Tags: discussion

I just got a *good question* in a review audit, upvoted it, got congratulated - all well so far.

**But** my upvote didn't count - so I had to perform that extra step and upvote the question for real.

<sub>This is no complaint, nothing like a bug report, just a heads up</sub>

Comment: It'll also trigger the audit system. I've upvoted comments on audit reviews and failed because of it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Really? That sounds like a bug to me. Comments could very likely *disagree* with the post. Upvoting them shouldn't count as anything. Perhaps you failed the audit because you *didn't* take some other action (e.g. downvote or flag)?

Comment: @Nateowami nope. As soon as I upvote, I fail.

Comment: I tested this today and could not reproduce your experience. I upvoted a question in the review queue and it stuck - when I revisited the question my vote was still there. Can you still reproduce this?